# Ads-script to duplicate rows in a sheet while iterating

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-ads-api

1. When I run an ads-script to call the "spreadsheet" API.
   I want to enrich a sheet by duplicating some rows according to values I have in a script.

How should I do this effectively?

only by creating a new tab? Starting from the last row?
As I change the range while iterating.

```
  for ( i = 0; i < lastColumn - 1; i++){
    for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow - 1; j++){
      var kw_data = kw_to_label[rangeValues[j][i]];
        if(kw_data != null){
        sheet.getRange(j,i).setValue(kw_data.labels[k]);
```

An example:

```
dict:
k1 -> val1, val2
k2 -> val3
```

and sheet:

[image]

Comment: Are you overwriting the data with the dict or just inserting the new values in the dict?

Comment: Ads Script or Apps Script? SpreadsheetApp or Spreadsheet API? "When I run an ads-script to call the 'spreadsheet' API" what do you mean? and please add the rest of the necessary code for us to reproduce